# T of F. The dihedral group $D_n$ has a subgroup of index $2.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

True or false. The dihedral group $D_n$ has a subgroup of index $2.$

My attempt: True.

Proof: $D_n$ has $n-1$ rotation, $n$ reflections, and $1$ identity element. Therefore, the number of elements of $D_n$ (order) is:

$n-1+n+1=2n$

Therefore the order of $D_n$ is always even. The order of a subgroup H must divide the order of the parent group. So this implies the index of $D_n$:

$|D_n|/|H| = 2$

$|2n|/|H|=2$

Therefore, you can always find an $H$ such that its order is a factor of $2$.

Comment: Your last line doesn't follow from what is above. Just show that every group of even order has an element $x$ such that $x^2=e$ (hint, consider $x$ and $x^{-1}$ if no such element exists - what is the order of $G$?).

Comment: well in my proof, if i divide both sides by 2, it means that that you can find an $H$ that is smaller than $D_n$ and that is divisible by $2n$

Comment: You need to show that such a subgroup $H$ exists though.

Comment: You have shown that $|D_n|$ is even, but just because the order of the group is even doesn't mean that there is a subgroup of index 2.

Comment: I get what you're saying now @DougM ! is there a way to prove that this subgroup exists following my proof?

Comment: You say there are $n-1$ rotations + 1 identity element.  Is this a subgroup?

Comment: Try to find a homomophism $f: D_n \rightarrow H$ to a group of order $n$.